# Gmail Attachment processing, Base64DecoderStream to InputStream

Tags: java, amazon-s3, gmail, inputstream, attachment

I need to fetch attachment from the GMail and upload it to the Amazon S3.

I am using **imap**, to connect to the GMail and am able to access the attachment, 
Using the javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart, which provides the getInputStream() which comes in the Base64DecoderStream , instead of FileInputStream or the ByteArray input stream.
Since my file is a Binary file(like .zip).

I need the InputStream to upload it to the S3.

**So how can i convert the Base64DecoderStream to InputStream?**

```
public void processMails() {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    Session session = null;
    Store store = null;
    session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    Folder inboxFolder;
    try {
        store = session.getStore();

        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "test@gmail.com", "password");
        inboxFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inboxFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        Message messages[] = inboxFolder.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));   

        for (Message msg : messages) {

            try {
                Multipart multiPart = (Multipart)msg.getContent();
                for (int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++) {
                    MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);
                    if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {

 InputStream stream = null;// need to convert part.getInputStream() to InputStream

                        processAttachment(stream);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
}
```

//The function for uploading is given below

```
public void processAttachment(InputStream asset) {

        ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
            if (asset instanceof FileInputStream) {
                meta.setContentLength(((FileInputStream)asset).available());
            } else if (asset instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
                meta.setContentLength(((ByteArrayInputStream)asset).available());
            } 
            else {
                meta.setContentLength(asset.available());
            } 

        s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucket, "parentfolder/subfolder/abc.zip", asset, meta));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you need entire msg to a stream.**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
msg.writeTo(bos);
bos.close();
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
```

**If you need only Content Try this**

```
InputStream base64InputStream = (InputStream) part.getInputStream();
int i = 0;
byte[] byteArray = new byte[base64InputStream.available()];
while ((i = (int) ((InputStream) base64InputStream).available()) > 0) {
    int result = (int) (((InputStream) base64InputStream).read(byteArray));
    if (result == -1)
        break;
}
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
```